# Preferred Network Mode not changing over ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to change the preferred network of android over adb through this command:

```
 settings put global preferred_network_mode 2
```

which is WCDMA only. But it's not updating in the phone. The phone is still in LTE only mode.

I also found that it can be done using

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "update global SET value=12 WHERE name='preferred_network_mode'" #command. However I don't sqllite3 installed so I couldn't test this.
```

What's the reason it's not working through settings command?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change mode in all places in settings, to do so You first need to list them like so:

```
adb shell settings list global | grep preferred
```

You might get output similar to this:

```
preferred_network_mode0=1
preferred_network_mode1=1
preferred_network_mode2=1
user_preferred_network_mode1=1
user_preferred_network_mode=1
```

Then for each setting You set Your preferred network mode using command You provided. After that You might need to turn airplane mode on, and off. Also, it might not work on Samsung devices for some reason